# How to access Gradle extra properties from Java?

Tags: java, android, testing, gradle, automated-tests

I'm doing some espresso tests for my application and i'm interacting with a real API from my tests. So, I'm trying to read those API credentials from some environment variables:

Let's say I'm using Netflix API. I declare the credentials in `bash_profile` on MAC:

```
export NETFLIX_ID='123'
export NETFLIX_TOKEN='xxx'
launchctl setenv NETFLIX_ID $NETFLIX_ID
launchctl setenv NETFLIX_TOKEN $NETFLIX_TOKEN
```

Now on Gradle, I create some extra properties, like this:

```
ext {
  netflixId = System.getenv("NETFLIX_ID")
  netflixToken = System.getenv("NETFLIX_TOKEN")
}
```

If I print `netflixId` and `netflixToken` the credentials are printed correctly, meaning `System.getenv()` is working.

What I'm trying to do now is to read those extra properties from Java code. Do you know if there is a way to do that? or a better approach? any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the values of the environment variables into your application. You can put those in build config fields in `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "String", "NETFLIX_ID", "\"" + System.getenv('NETFLIX_ID') + "\""
    }
}
```

These values then end up in the compile time generated `BuildConfig` class in the package corresponding to that gradle module's AndroidManifest package, and you can then use `BuildConfig.NETFLIX_ID` to use the value.

Comment: how to achieve the same result in simple project which is not android